# Embeding Youtube Video small dimensions but still HD quality

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

Having trouble embedding a YouTube into my blog at blogger.com. I wanted a video with the dimensions below to still play in HD. I think my problem is not knowing what I need to change and then where to post the code in my blog.

I've been reading and trying for over 6 hours and still can't get it.

```
width="655" 
height="380"
```

I found sound helpful code from biostall but can't get it to work for me. I put the JS code into a JS/HTML gadget on my blog, and then posted the HTML into a new post and tried posting it with both settings Show HTML literally and Interpret typed HTML.

There's a really helpful code **[from biostall](http://biostall.com/the-100-guaranteed-method-to-get-youtube-iframe-embeds-playing-in-hd-by-default/)**.

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="player"></div>
```

**The Javascript:**

```
// 1. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.  
 var tag = document.createElement('script');  

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";  
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];  
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);  

// 2. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player) after the API code downloads.  
var player;  
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {  
    player = new YT.Player('player', {  
        height: '1280',  
        width: '720',  
        videoId: 'E37YNMYlKvo',  
        events: {  
            'onReady': onPlayerReady  
        }  
    });  
}  

// 3. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.  
function onPlayerReady(event) {  
    player.setPlaybackQuality('hd1080'); // Here we set the quality (yay!)  
    event.target.playVideo(); // Optional. Means video autoplays  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so you have an object `YT.Player` with props height,width,videoId,events

Try change to

```
height: '380' 

width: '655'
```

so

```
var player;  
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {  
    player = new YT.Player('player', {  
        height: '380',  
        width: '655',  
        videoId: 'E37YNMYlKvo',  
        events: {  
            'onReady': onPlayerReady  
        }  
    });  
}
```

...

remain `player.setPlaybackQuality('hd1080'); // Here we set the quality (yay!)`

because it sets the quality

btw you have two 'types' 720p and 1080p

## recap

change only height and width